# How to declare a constant in BASIC

Tags: basic, qbasic

Unfortunately, I’m having trouble figuring out how to do some things, because Google is clogged with tutorials of “programming basics” and Visual Basic.

So I have to ask: in old-skool BASIC, I know I can use constants like `#RED`, but how do I **define** a constant?

Comment: This might be better for retrocomputing SE, but afaik, there are a multitude of "old-skool" BASICs and many likely have variations in syntax

Comment: As James eluded to, there is no one correct answer, however -most- versions of BASIC used the keyword CONST.  Those that did not have such a keyword the programmer usually had his/her own style of naming including all capital letters, underscores, pre-pending names with "CONST_" or some similar method to regular variables.  I'm not aware of -any- flavor of BASIC that would have recognized "#RED"

Comment: I honestly don't remember any "old-school" BASICs that actually supported constants; those that did, mostly post-dated QBASIC/QuickBASIC.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in most dialects of Qbasic allow the value of a number to be assigned to a constant, such as:

```
10 CONST VALUE = 10
```

then other constants can include them:

```
20 CONST VALUE2 = VALUE * VALUE
```

there is also the DEF FN function which includes a declared function..

Answer (score -1):

In most dialects of Qbasic there is a declared function:

```
DEF FNA(X) = X * 10
PRINT FNA(10)
```

which declares the defined function.